# Concatenate arrays with different shape duplicating values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have one array with shape: `(15,2)`. I also have another array with values: `[0, 3, 5]`.

I want to create another column in the first array with values from the second array, where the first 5 rows has value 0, rows 6-10 has value 3, and the last 5 rows has value 5.

like so:

```
[0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 3,
 3,
 3,
 3,
 3,
 5,
 5,
 5,
 5,
 5]
```

is there any numpy method that does that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy's built-in `repeat` and `stack`ing:

```
a = np.zeros((15,2))
b = np.array([0,3,5])
np.hstack((a, np.repeat(b,5)[:,None]))
```

output:

```
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 3.]
 [0. 0. 3.]
 [0. 0. 3.]
 [0. 0. 3.]
 [0. 0. 3.]
 [0. 0. 5.]
 [0. 0. 5.]
 [0. 0. 5.]
 [0. 0. 5.]
 [0. 0. 5.]]
```

Comment: Thanks! One question, what does it mean the `[:,None]` slicing?

Comment: @joann2555 `None` adds an extra dimension to array (in the place it is added, here 2nd dimension in `[:,None]`). It is an alias for `np.newaxis`.  Basically, we are adding another dimension so that when we stack, we stack correct dimensions together.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

- Convert your second array int a 2d "vector" array where each row has 1 column

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5] # your list of [0, 3, 5]
a = np.array([a]).T # [ [0], [0], [0], ..., [5] ] the "vector" array
```

then simply

```
b = np.array([[i, i +1] for i in range(15)]) # some example 15x2 array
print(np.concatenate((b, a), axis=1))
```

The output is

```
array([[ 0,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  2,  0],
       [ 2,  3,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  0],
       [ 5,  6,  3],
       [ 6,  7,  3],
       [ 7,  8,  3],
       [ 8,  9,  3],
       [ 9, 10,  3],
       [10, 11,  5],
       [11, 12,  5],
       [12, 13,  5],
       [13, 14,  5],
       [14, 15,  5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
rand = np.random.random((15,2)) # shape is (15,2)
vals = np.array([0,3,5]) # shape is (3,)
res = np.concatenate(([np.full((rand.shape[0]//vals.shape[0],), val) for val in vals]), axis=0)
res
```

output:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
```

Finally,

```py
final = np.hstack((rand, res.reshape(15,1)))
final
```

output:

```
array([[0.29759807, 0.60548479, 0.        ],
       [0.61242249, 0.46456274, 0.        ],
       [0.86172011, 0.2963868 , 0.        ],
       [0.91728575, 0.36366023, 0.        ],
       [0.56488556, 0.82130321, 0.        ],
       [0.59482141, 0.46148353, 3.        ],
       [0.7762271 , 0.25415058, 3.        ],
       [0.09176551, 0.9687253 , 3.        ],
       [0.06473259, 0.34686598, 3.        ],
       [0.69542414, 0.15540001, 3.        ],
       [0.02880707, 0.23169327, 5.        ],
       [0.90004256, 0.22145591, 5.        ],
       [0.61596969, 0.46807342, 5.        ],
       [0.02263769, 0.68522023, 5.        ],
       [0.81777274, 0.58145853, 5.        ]])
```